# Проблема с выводом адресов элементов строки

Tags: c++

Можете обьяснить почему при выводе адресов элементов массива string вместо адресов выводится строка с указанного адреса ? Что в коде неверно и как получить адреса элементов строки

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int size = 5;
    int array[size] = { 2,4,6,8,10 };
    char string[size] = "2468";
    int i;

    // Массив int
    cout << "i" << '\t' << "Address" << '\t' << "Value\n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << i << '\t' << array + i << '\t' << *(array + i) << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // Массив char
    cout << "i" << '\t' << "Address" << '\t' << "Value\n\n";
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << i << '\t' << string + i << '\t' << *(string + i) << endl;
    cout << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Потому что наследие си. Указатель на char трактуется как строка. Приводите к void*

Comment: (void*)(string + i) вместо string+i ?

Comment: Или даже `static_cast<const void*>(string + i)` вместо `string + i`.

Comment: да. пробуйте. Возможно и в других местах также

Comment: Спасибо , разобрался

Comment: imho лучше даже писать так --  `printf("%d\t%p\t%s\n", i, string + i, string + i);`